# What is the "kedusha of the individual"?

Tags: tefilla, kedusha-prayer, manuscripts

In a 13th century manuscript of a machzor according to Minhag Ashkenaz ([Bibliothèque Nationale de France, Hébreu 644](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b107201263)), on the pages for the kedusha on Shabbat for shacharit and mussaf, there is an additional "kedusha" alongside the chazan's kedusha. It's indicated as "קדושה ראשונה של יחיד" in Shacharit ([here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b107201263/f7.item)) and as "קדושה של שבת {שאו?}  יחיד" in Mussaf ([here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b107201263/f12.item)).

The texts seem to be intended for a regular Shabbat, and the chazan's kedusha that appears alongside includes no piyyutim. The "individual kedushas" themselves are alphabetic and interweave the kedusha text with other phrases. For example, the Shacharit text starts:

> ‮**א**ין כאל מעריצים במוראות **ב**שערים זרויים [!] לארבע הפאות ואומ[ר] ק[דוש] ק[דוש] ק[דוש] יי צבאות. **ג**אה על גאים נשגב לבדו **ד**גליו מעירים כי אין בלעדו, מלא כל הארץ כבודו...

Does anyone know what this is, what its purpose is (intended for during the chazan's repitition, like modim derabannan, or during the silent shmoneh esreh), and where I could read more about it?

Comment: Elaborate Kedusha piyut would have been standard in special repetitions (see the back of artscroll machzor for rosh hashana, for instance). I still suspect this is some variation on that genre. Whether it's presented as an alternate for the Chazzan or for call-and-response format or something else.

Comment: Here it is again with the author https://web.nli.org.il/sites/nli/english/digitallibrary/pages/viewer.aspx?presentorid=MANUSCRIPTS&docid=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS000171927-1#|FL10243496

Comment: @DoubleAA Nice find. Odd that the MS is listed as "ליחיד" but the MS itself doesn't mention that at all. Perhaps that's referring only to the non-kedusha parts, which clearly *are* written for an individual.